# laravel 5.4 : Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

i'm testing password reset in laravel 5.4 and i got this error :

```
    Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError j71sm516784wmd.12 - gsmtp
"
```

here is my `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and my `mail.php`

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),

'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'from me'),

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

'username' => env('myemail@gmail.com'),

'password' => env('mypassword'),
```

i Tryed to turn on "less secure apps" of my gmail account.nothing change
How do I resolve this error message?
could anyone help me please !!!

Comment: do you have two steps verification switched on your account? If so you need to create an app specific password and use that password

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this by changing:

```
'username' => env('my-email'),
'password' => env('my-password'),
```

to

```
'username' => 'my-email',
'password' => 'my-password',
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and what i did was

go to google settings for enabling 2 step varification from [here](https://myaccount.google.com/security) or follow [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en)

after turning on 2 step verification `App Password` link will appear right below 2 step verification. Which will take you to [this](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords?rapt=AEjHL4O8twl7X_jElUvr0_oBgB5abGhlbukNdkLIj1-3wIOTqLhjQfsx6_3qvPQReUmI5pTOHQCSfxy4QHkIH4ZEGdMtdOB1Qw) link

Then create your app password by following the [process](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

then copy the app password that is generated and paste it in your `.env` file like follows

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=DomainName
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_GMAIL@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_GMAIL_CREATED_APP_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

also be sure to check both `smtp` and `sendmail` in `MAIL_DRIVER` 

Also run `php artisan config:cache`

 Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT=587
 MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
 MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in your `.env` file.

And you need 2-steps authentication for your Google account.

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
I also getting same issue but finally I reached by below credentials

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your-email
MAIL_PASSWORD=your-password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls


Also enable **Allow less secure apps** in your gmail account follow link: https://myaccount.google.com/u/3/security

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

After enabling logging to the mail from the less secured devices, make sure that `.env` file contains the following configurations:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="your_passwrod_here"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Make sure that your password is rounded by the double quotes "" .
And make sure that your mail.php file contains configurations like the following:

```
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'your_email@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'your_email'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

and don't forget to close the server and run "php artisan config:clear" to clear the configuration cache.

Answer (score 0):

Also please change code like this in `mail.php`:

```
 'username' =>  env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'my-email'),
 'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'my-password'),
```

Answer (score 0):

When you edit your .env file with the MAIL_ attributes... don't forget to scroll down and delete the default MAIL_ values included by default, or default will clobber your entered values because they are later in the file!